# Creating an Instead of insert Trigger SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a DBA with my company. I am trying to create trigger that will check any insert statement for duplicates first then if none allow the original insert. Not even sure this can be done. The insert statements may be written by various users so the statements will never be the same. All I have found so far is the check for duplicates but the insert statement is then hard coded in the trigger. My plan is also to check update as well, but it is not important right now.

Here is my current code.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[BlockDuplicatesOnTable]
ON [dbo].[blockduplicates]
Instead of INSERT, Update
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


Declare @ProviderAcctNumber nvarchar(50)
Declare @Referredby int

Declare @Action as char(1)
Declare @Count as int
Set @Action = 'I'
Select @Count = Count(*) from DELETED
IF @Count > 0
Begin
Set @Action = 'D'
Select @Count = count(*) from INSERTED
IF @Count > 0
Set @Action = 'U'

    IF @Action = 'I'

    Begin
    IF not exists (Select 1 from inserted as i
    inner join dbo.blockduplicates as b
    on i.ProviderAcctNumber = b.ProviderAcctNumber
        and i.Referredby = b.Referredby)
    Begin
        --execute original insert
    End
    Else 
    Begin
        Print 'Duplicate insert'
        Raiserror ('Duplicate Entry for Insert',16,1);
        Return
    End
    End
Else IF @Action = 'U'

Begin

Select @ProviderAcctNumber = ProviderAcctNumber, @Referredby = Referredby from inserted
IF Not exists (Select 1 from deleted where ProviderAcctNumber = @ProviderAcctNumber and Referredby = @Referredby)
    Begin
        Print 'Update Statement is True';
    End
    Else 
    Begin
        Print 'duplicate'
        Raiserror ('Duplicate Entry for Update',16,1);
        Return
    End
End
End
End;
```

Comment: Why not just have a `UNIQUE` constraint? Don't see a need for a trigger here.

Comment: *I am trying to create trigger that will check any insert statement for duplicates first then if none allow the original insert.*. So, you need unique values. Use `UNIQUE` constraint as mentioned by @Damien_The_Unbeliever. That would be the easier solution.

Comment: That is my plan but as it stands there are numerous duplicates that do exist. I am trying to prevent further duplicates until these can be cleaned up. There is a ton of cleanup that I have inherited.

Comment: create constraint with nocheck option http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43823/can-i-add-a-unique-constraint-that-ignores-existing-violations

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try this first.